# Runge–Kutta of 4th order with the problem of f=alpha*y-beta*(y*y) with Python

Tags: python, plot, graph, runge-kutta

so I've been working lately in a project that requires to write a python program that gives as an output a graph for Runge–Kutta of 4th order with the problem of `f=alpha*y-beta*(y*y)`.

So can anyone help me please cause I'm finding a lot of problems with my programs and YouTube didn't help much,
so my idea was to save the `y` values in a list and then from that list i will try to draw the graph using plot, but the list is  not showing

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f(x):
    alpha = input("Enter the value of ⍺: ")
    beta = input("Enter the value of β: ")
    
    return alpha*y[0]-beta*(y[0]*y[0]) 
    

def runge_k(y, t, h):
    list = [] 
    i = 0
    while i < t:
        k1 = h*f(y)
        t = t
        k2 = h*f(y+k1/2)
        t = t+h
        k3 = h*f(y+k2/2)
        t = t+h
        k4 = h*f(y+k3)
        t = t+h
        y = y+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
        list.append(y)  
        i=i+1
    return list 


H = float(input("Enter the value of H: "))
Y = float(input("Enter the first value of Y:  "))
x = 100.0

l = runge_k(Y,100,H)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### big stuff

Now you need to remove the `t=t+h` commands, as `t` is the fixed final time while `i` is the running time that needs to be updated as `i=i+h`. Or if you want to keep `i` integer, the loop condition should be `while i*h < t:`

You do not want to input the parameters `alpha` and `beta` in each of the hundreds of calls to `f`. Global variable values are available without passing them as parameters.

#### small stuff

It is usually a bad idea to use keywords like `list` as variable names.

If you do not need `x=100.0`, then please remove it in the minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

i just changed my code to this and it showed the y list, now all i need is a time list and i would be able to draw the graph:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f(y):
    return float(alpha) * float(y) - float(beta) * (float(y) * float(y))


def runge_k(y, t, h):
    list_y = []
    #list_t = []
    i = 0
    while i < t:
        k1 = h * f(y)
        k2 = h * f(y + k1 / 2)
        k3 = h * f(y + k2 / 2)
        k4 = h * f(y + k3)
        y = y + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6
        list_y.append(y)
        #t = t + h 
        i = i + 1
    return list_y


alpha = input("Enter the value of ⍺: ")
beta = input("Enter the value of β: ")
H = float(input("Enter the value of H: "))
Y = float(input("Enter the first value of Y:  "))
x = 100.0

l = runge_k(Y, 100, H)
print(l)
```

Comment: You need to separate the end time that you get as parameter from the running time that you can use to build `list_t`. It would be easiest to rename the parameter as `t_end`.